# Smartthings Groovy scheduling limitations workaround

Tags: groovy, cloud, scheduled-tasks, smartthings

According to Smartthings documentation, [only 4 jobs can be scheduled at once](http://docs.smartthings.com/en/latest/smartapp-developers-guide/scheduling.html#scheduling-limitations-best-practices-and-things-good-to-know). I'm curious if this limit applies to all applications installed on a hub, or a namespace, or a single application. Even still, I have two single applications that require more than four scheduling times. A [saltwater light controller](https://github.com/blaher/YoungHome/blob/97507094b2f6412f006c983e4759f29ea7245d1d/Apps/AquariumSWController.groovy) and a similar [freshwater light controller](https://github.com/blaher/YoungHome/blob/97507094b2f6412f006c983e4759f29ea7245d1d/Apps/AquariumFWController.groovy). I also of course have other applications in the household that use scheduling. I can change the namespace to separate them if needed, I wasn't even sure of the best practice. You can view my code in the links provided, but does anyone know a work around to this limitation? I know I could probably write something up where it applies runIn() after a start schedule() to lower the count, but it doesn't specify if both runIn() and schedule() combined count against that limit. Anyone have any experience with dealing with this?

Comment: I did think of a work around, but I'm unsure if it's the best way to do it. It would require one schedule (once a day at the beginning), and each step in time would be a new function to run which would do a runIn() to step to the next action. I would also have to introduce conditionals, since I have weekday conditional crons. It would be a long chain of runIn()s, and it could end up being confusing, but is this really the best way to get around this limitation?